# Hardening android to use it as a Linux Server

Tags: security, linux, termux

I want to convert a set of relatively old Android devices into Linux servers, while avoiding too many device specific actions, to make this an easily repeatable and shareable action.
This means avoiding working with custom ROMs and root, as these are usually very device specific.

Thankfully, software like Termux, UserLAnd, linuxdeploy and Androinix make it possible to use Linux environments without changing OS, which while a bit limiting gives us access to a lot of key tools, from bash to SSH, Clang, Python and more

The issue then becomes how to harden such a device so that it can be used not just as an isolated machine but can be marginally exposed to a network.

My first instinct is to put it behind a firewall, perhaps both a network one and software one internally, blocking any incoming connections, perhaps with the exception of a VPN/SSH access with keys only.
Another step would be to use ADB to block/uninstall most non-necessary apps, like  browsers or email clients.
I was considering blocking outwards connections, perhaps using a VPN that selectively blocks any non-whitelisted app.

I'm not a security expert, and I'm not sure if this would be a sufficient approach, considering how many if these devices have pretty old versions of Android, so i wanted to know if anyone has other approaches and ideas

Comment: This is going to be complicated and time-consuming and if it succeeds, will give you a bunch of separate Linux servers that are isolated from each other. It would be a *lot* easier to buy an Intel NUC PC and run a conventional server Linux.